# What version of the song "Rock Me" was popular in the 1960s?

Tags: rock, unknown-performer

In the mid-1960s I listened to 2 AM radio stations in Southern California: KHJ and KFWB. The DJs included Sam Riddle, The Real Don Steele, and Humble Harv. A song has come to mind recently that may be have been titled "Rock Me (Baby)" and I remember it being played at that time on a pretty regular basis. I thought it was by The Doors but I have only found a listing of a live Doors medley that includes this title. A few days ago I heard a version of the exact song playing on Directv Channel 840 and it was titled "Rock Me" and was by Steppenwolf (of "Born to be Wild" and "Magic Carpet Ride" fame). Can anyone  remember if this could have been the same version that was so popular back in the 60s? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Probably "Rock Me Baby" by the Animals on *Animalism*. Eric Burdon sounds like Jim Morrison a little.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CzYvHlGq57E

Hendrix does a different version at Monterey, but he "quotes" the Animals version.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lr4VC_hqFHE